# Getting '�' or '@' symbol when reading from text file with fread

Tags: c, file, io, fread

I want to read 80 characters from a text file, save them to a string and then print that string for verification.
I am using fread and have this code:

```
char message[80];
size_t nread = fread(message, 1, sizeof(message), fp);
printf("Message received: \"__%s__\"\n", message);
```

And the output is:

> Message received: "__I would love to change the world but they won't
>   ��__"

when the whole phrase isn't in the file

and:

> __I would love to change the world but they won't give me the source code
>    @__

when the whole phrase is in the file.

I've tried deleting it and rewriting the text but I get the same output again.

What is wrong? Something with the charset?

Comment: @cnicutar, if it read `80` then that would be one past the end of `message`.

Comment: @hmjd Yeah, `nread` must be checked prior to this. Or just passs sizeof - 1 to `fread`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`fread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) does not null terminate the buffer and `prinf("%s")` expects the buffer to be null terminated. As the buffer is not null terminated `printf()` will continue reading until it finds a null terminator, printing out any junk along the way.

Either null terminate the buffer, remembering to leave room for the null terminator:

```
char message[81]; /* Increased by 1 for null terminator. */
size_t nread = fread(message, 1, sizeof(message) - 1, fp);
message[nread] = 0;
printf("Message received: \"__%s__\"\n", message);
```

or instruct `printf()` to only print the number of characters read using `"%.*s"` format specifier:

```
printf("Message received: \"__%.*s__\"\n", nread, message);
```

Comment: Great! I thought it did null terminate the buffer with _message[nread] = '\0';_. So I think I will null terminate it. But could you explain me what is that you are doing with printf? with the '*' we mean the nread variable?

Comment: @Chris, `"%.*s"` is a format specifier that requires two arguments: a length and a buffer. It instructs `printf()` to print the first `nread` characters from `message`, eliminating the requirement for a null terminator in `message`.

Comment: Thank you! I actually didn't know that for printf.